# Unity2D: I Can't do a WallJump

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unityscript

My Wall Jump Was Working Normally But I Were trying to add collider detector for my enemy then that happens : https://streamable.com/wjfftn
Can you Guys Help Me With it
this is my Wall Jump Script
public float WallSlidForce;

public float WallJumpDuration = 0.3f;

private float WallSlideDirection;

private float WallJumpTimer = 0.2f;

private float WallJumpTime;

public bool IsWallSliding;

private bool IsWallJumping;

void Update()

{

if ( CanMove)

{

if (!IsCroushing )

rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalMovement * WalkForce, rb.velocity.y);

else if (IsCroushing)

rb.velocity = new Vector2(HorizontalMovement * CroushForce, rb.velocity.y);

Flip();

}

Animation();

WallSliding();

WallJump();

MoveChecking();

}

public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)

{

if (context.performed && !IsDashing && !IsCroushing)

{

if (!IsWallSliding && JumpLeft > 0 && !Ck.IsGrounded)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpForce);

JumpLeft--;

Jump2 = true;

}

if (Ck.IsGrounded)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpForce);

}

}

else if (context.canceled)

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x,rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);

if (context.performed && WallJumpTime > 0f && !IsCroushing)

{

if (HorizontalMovement != 0)

{

IsWallJumping = true;

rb.velocity = new Vector2(WallSlideDirection * WallJumpForce.x, WallJumpForce.y);

WallJumpTime = 0f;

}

else

{

IsWallJumping= true;

rb.velocity = new Vector2 (WallSlideDirection * WallJumpForce.x , rb.velocity.y);

WallJumpTime = 0f;

}

if (transform.localScale.x != WallSlideDirection)

{

IsFacingRight = !IsFacingRight;

Vector2 ls = transform.localScale;

ls.x *= -1f;

transform.localScale = ls;

}

Invoke(nameof(StopWallJump),WallJumpDuration);

}

if (context.performed && IsCroushing && !Ck.IsTouchingFloor)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, JumpForce);

StopCroushing();

}

}

private void MoveChecking()

{

if (!IsWallSliding && !IsDashing && !IsSliding && !IsWallJumping && !IsAttacking)

CanMove = true;

else CanMove = false;

}

private void WallSliding()

{

if (Ck.IsTouchingWall && !Ck.IsGrounded && !IsDashing)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -WallSlidForce);

IsWallSliding = true;

}

else IsWallSliding = false;

}

private void WallJump()

{

if (IsWallSliding)

{

IsWallJumping = false;

WallSlideDirection = -transform.localScale.x;

WallJumpTime = WallJumpTimer;

CancelInvoke(nameof(StopWallJump));

}

else WallJumpTime -= Time.deltaTime;

}

private void StopWallJump()

{

IsWallJumping = false;

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQVCA.png)

I want To fix my problem a know why that happening.

Comment: Anyway I found Solution by my self . if you have the same problem you just need to add if you Wall Jumping you need to stop Wall Sliding

Like That 


private void WallSliding()

{

if (Ck.IsTouchingWall && !Ck.IsGrounded && !IsDashing && !IsWallJumping)

{

rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, -WallSlidForce);

IsWallSliding = true;

}

else IsWallSliding = false;

}

Comment: next time please use code tags to make that mess readable